# .png image to numpy array conversion code error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, spyder

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = Image.open(r'D:\New folder (2)')
data = np.array(img,dtype='uint8')
np.save('long.png',data)
img_array = np.load('long.png')
plt.imshow(img_array)
```

When I run this code I get an error saying:

> ```
> File "C:\Users\prudhvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line  2580, in open
>
>     fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\New folder (2)'
> ```

Please also suggest improvements to the code.

Comment: Looks like your windows doesn't allow access to `D:` drive. Go to properties and give full access.

Comment: I started python as run as administrator

Comment: Try moving your folder to a more accessible location, like desktop. And look at your `Image.open()`. You have given folder name only, give a complete path to the file.

Comment: Thanks it works but i have error at line 7 
  File "C:\Users\prudhvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 384, in load
    fid = open(file, "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'long.png'

Comment: Don't keep changing the question after you resolve your previous question. This error is fresh and completely unrelated to your previous issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `Image.open()` must be a filename (with or without the full path depending on your working directory). You have supplied it with a folder name. So for me

```
Image.open("C:\Python27")
```

will give me the same error.

The solution is to include your image filename (including the extension) as well as the path:

```
Image.open("C:\Python27\my_image.png")
```

You could of course change the current working directory which means you can just pass the filename rather than the full path:

```
import os
os.chdir("D:\New folder (2)")
```

Comment: thank you it works but i have another error at line 7 which states 
  File "C:\Users\prudhvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 384, in load
    fid = open(file, "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'long.png'

Comment: @PrudhviReddy You're probably not providing the full file path to `open()`, so Python will be looking in your current working directory, not the directory where the file is